# How to convert Mono<List<String>> into Flux<String>

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm converting small project written in RxJava 1.x to Reactor 3.x. All is good, except that I could not find out how to replace `flatMap(Observable::from)` with an appropriate counterpart. I have `Mono<List<String>>` and I need to convert it to `Flux<String>`.

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/java-mono-list-to-flux

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In Reactor 3, the `from` operator has been specialized into a few variants, depending on the original source (array, iterable, etc...).

Use `yourMono.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)` in your case.

Comment: The return value of method [Mono.flatMap](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/v3.1.5.RELEASE/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.java#L2071) is Mono, not Flux.

Comment: @SimonBaslé why does the member reference operator does not work in kotlin?
` Mono.just(listOfElements).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)`
 //this does not work `
I have to write code like the one below


`Mono.just(listOfElements).flatMapMany{ ` Flux.fromIterable(it)  } `

Comment: @rhozet no idea, that works in Java AFAIK so... question for kotlin compiler specialists?

Comment: yes it works in Java, probably question for compiler specialists :)

Comment: I believe https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13003 is why the function reference doesn't work in Kotlin

Answer (score 9):

I think that probably `Flux::mergeSequential` static factory fits better here:

```
 Iterable<Mono<String>> monos = ...
 Flux<String> f = Flux.mergeSequential(monos);
```

This kind of merge (sequential) will maintain the ordering inside given source iterable, and will also subscribe/request eagerly from all participating sources (so more parallelization expected while computing mono results).

Comment: Note that `Flux.mergeSequential` subscribes to each source sequentially without waiting for completion in between. If you strictly need the next `Mono` to happen after the previous one has finished (e.g. you're publishing to an event queue and order matters), you should use `Flux.concat(monos)`.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Simon, I implemented something like this:

```
List<Object> dbObjects = ListObjectsBD();
    List<Dao> daos = mapperObjToDao(dbObjects);
    Flux<Dao> daoFlux = Mono.just(daos).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be using [flatMapIterable()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMapIterable-java.util.function.Function-)

> Transform the item emitted by this Mono into Iterable, then forward
> its elements into the returned Flux.

So it looks like this:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("hello");
strings.add("world");
strings.add("!");

Mono<List<String>> monoList = Mono.just(strings);

Flux<String> flux = monoList.flatMapIterable(list -> list);
```

Or replace lambda `list -> list` with `Function.identity()`

```
Flux<String> flux = monoList.flatMapIterable(Function.identity());
```