# Convert Mono<List<MyObject>> to Flux<MyObject> in spring 5

Tags: spring, reactive-programming

I have making a get call and the response is mapped to mono having list of objects using body to Mono.

Now I want to return a Flux type for this object.How do I achieve this to convert
 `Mono<List<MyObject>> to Flux<MyObject>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Mono<List<String>> into Flux<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007841/how-to-convert-monoliststring-into-fluxstring)

Answer (score 1):

Example for `String` type:

`Mono<List<String>> mono`

`Flux<String> flux = mono.flux().flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)`

Answer (score 0):

To convert Mono to flux, the `.flux()` method can be used

```
Mono<String> monoObject= Mono.just("Pratik");

Flux<String> fluxObject = monoObject.flux();
```