# How to convert nested list in Mono to Flux?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I am very new to reactive-streams, Can someone help me to convert `Mono<MyClass>` to `Flux<Integer>`

I tried something like this -

```java
Flux<Integer> myMethod(Mono<MyClass> homeWork) {
    return homeWork.map(h -> h.multiplicands)
              .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable).map(m -> h*m);
}
```

```java
public class MyClass{
    int multiplier;
    List<Integer> multiplicands;
}
```

I am expecting the result of multiplier * (each) multiplicand in `Flux<Integer>` format.

Can you help me with the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007841/how-to-convert-monoliststring-into-fluxstring

Comment: @sambit I looked into that post my mono is `Mono<MyClass>` not in `Mono<List>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the instance of `MyClass` into a `Stream<Integer>` which contains multiplied integers and then turn `Mono<Stream<Integer>>` into `Flux<Integer>`:

```
Flux<Integer> myMethod(Mono<MyClass> homeWork) {
  return homeWork
           .map(hw -> hw.multiplicands.stream().map(m -> m * hw.multiplier))
           .flatMapMany(Flux::fromStream);
}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks for the answer. I have another question- Let's say if I have another property `List<Integer> results;` in `MyClass` and I want to update the multiplication results to `results` property. How to do that? -Thanks

Comment: You can do it in the map function, collecting the stream beforehand. However, I wouldn’t recommend changing state inside pipeline operations. It’s much safer to produce a new object with required charachteristics.